# PHP8.1-fpm doesn't start since server reboot

Tags: php

PHP8.1-fpm doesn't work on my debian11 server with apache2 since a reboot.

I tried several things remove and purge then reinstall without success.
In the error message failed to load php-fpm.conf but the file exist.

```
● php8.1-fpm.service - The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.1-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-06-21 23:30:56 UTC; 3min 17s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm8.1(8)
    Process: 7334 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.1 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
    Process: 7335 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 81 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 7334 (code=exited, status=78)
        CPU: 83ms

Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 php-fpm8.1[7334]: [21-Jun-2023 23:30:56] ERROR: [/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf:115] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 php-fpm8.1[7334]: PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in Unknown on line 1
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 php-fpm8.1[7334]: [21-Jun-2023 23:30:56] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 php-fpm8.1[7334]: [21-Jun-2023 23:30:56] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 systemd[1]: php8.1-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 systemd[1]: php8.1-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 21 23:30:56 freebox-vm-48064 systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

I don't know how to solve the issue...

Comment: The error does not say your file is missing, it says `ERROR: [/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf:115] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY` and it says `PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in Unknown on line 1` ending in `failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf'`, so all the text is telling you that you need to fix your config file. Did you look those errors up already?

Answer (score 0):

The socket is only created if the listen directive in the www.conf file says to listen on that socket. If it's not there then the listen directive probably says to listen on 127.0.0.1.

Importantly the socket is not a file - its a unix domain socket and creating a plain file with touch is more likely to prevent it from working than not. It's safe to delete the socket (and your file) as it is created automatically by php-fpm if the listen directive tells it to.

However your key problem is a syntax error in the conf file as the earlier poster pointed out. Locate the spurious brackets or characters and that should solve the problem and probably make the socket appear as php-fpm actually starts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I can't explain how it's append but the  php8.1-fpm.sock file was missing in the directory run/php. Go in and tip:

`sudo touch php8.1-fpm.sock`

then,
`systemctl restart php8.1-fpm.service`

Comment: Touching a socket file is never the answer, and this will likely break on next reboot. You probably need to fix the permissions so that FPM can _create_ the socket.